# Reverse-proxy for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker

Context: For our testing environment, we were migrating from on-premise SQL Server 2017 to Docker Linux SQL 2017 container. There is a large number of TestScripts in windows that try to connect to SQLServer in windows via trusted authentication. This Windows Authentication mode doesn't work with Docker Linux SqlServer as only SqlAuth is supported.

Question:
Is there a reverse-proxy that I can use to accept TrustedConnection from TestScripts requiring TrustedAuthentication and redirect the requests to Docker Linux SqlDb that accepts only SqlAuth?

- It is ok to pre-define SqlAuth for Docker Linux SqlDb in reverse-proxy.
- It is ok to skip or bypass or fake-validate any form of authentication from clients. Our test scenarios are mostly positive, and we don't need to validate Sql login failures.
- It is ok to run reverse-proxy in windows platform, for windows auth capability.

This was to avoid the work of re-writing/updating auth on large number of TestScripts (which are legacy). This is test code, and ok to ignore all the security implications.

Comment: You **can** use Windows/Kerberos Authentication on Linux, [with the proper configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you. But, the host machine, on which docker is hosted, is in WORKGROUP and not connected to any ActiveDirectory/DomainController. So, there are test-scripts that try to authenticate to SQL via local Windows Credentials of the host, for e.g., <machineName>\testuser. By looking at the link you provided, this scenario is not supported, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found TDSProxy useful for this purpose. This proxy handles and redirects on TDS protocol used for SQL auth.
Code change to enable my scenario: https://github.com/tech-software/TDSProxy/pull/3